# Limit of a recursive series as n approaches infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm unsure how to go about approaching this, but I'm working with some Riemann sums right now, and I want to show that the upper limit converges to $\,0.5$. I've run it in excel and I know it works out, but I'm having difficulty with the math. I'm really bad with series so hopefully someone could help me out.

I'm trying to find the limit of this:

$$\sum_1^n \big(\,x_i-x_{i-1}\,\big)\,x_i$$

Given a domain of $\,\left[0,\,1\right],\,$ I want to equally partition it such that the length of each partition is: $x_i-x_{i-1} = \dfrac{1}{n},\;0=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=1$

So then, what is $\;\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty \big(\,x_i-x_{i-1}\,\big)\,x_i$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
S_n
= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})x_i
= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}x_i
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n}
= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n i
= \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} 
= \frac{n+1}{2n}
= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}
$$
Thus $S_n\to \frac{1}{2}$ for $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks!!!! This is perfect.